# RXJS: Adding a function to Observable to execute when subscribed to (defer)

Tags: typescript, bluetooth, rxjs, observable, ionic3

### Adding a function to Observable to execute when subscribed to (defer)

I have an Observable made from events. In this case, Bluetooth notifications.

I want to run a function (startNotifictions) only when someone is subscribing to that Observable.

This code did work, on previous versions. It is with Ionic3 framework. It added a new operator, that ran when subscribed. Now the transpiler has a problem with the types, complaining twice, that the .doOnSubscribe is not available on typedef Observable any> and <{}>.

Anyone has an idea how to get that typed correctly? Extend maybe?
Tried to use .defer directly, no avail.

```js
 // add operator doOnSubscribe to the event observable
        Observable.prototype.doOnSubscribe = function(onSubscribe) {
            let source = this;
            return Observable.defer(() => {
                onSubscribe();
                return source;
            });
        };

        // return the Observable for the notify char, with startNotify on first subscribe
        getUartDataNote( Observable.fromEvent( this.uartChar, 'characteristicvaluechanged' )
            .doOnSubscribe(() => {
                console.log('starting note');
                this.uartChar.startNotifications();
            })
            .map( value => String.fromCharCode.apply( null, new Uint8Array( this.uartChar.value.buffer )))
            .takeUntil( Observable.fromEvent( this.gatt.device, 'gattserverdisconnected' ))
            .finally(() => {
                console.log( 'stream disconnected ');
                // not necessary: return this.uartChar.stopNotifications()
            })
            .share()
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you write the type augmentation.

```
export {}

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    doOnSubscribe(onSubscribe: () => void): this;
  }
}
```

This is documented in the [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) section of the TypeScript handbook.

Comment: `: this` surprises me a lot. Could you please point me to a document where it is being described? I've never seen anything like this one before.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko it was added in the TypeScript 2.0 timeframe. It states that the method returns the receiver. It enables partial higher-order polymorphism at the type level. For example, if you have a builder object it would make sense to use it. I only used it here because it is correct according to the implementation and it's more concise than having to import all the types and restate the generic

Comment: @JuergenKienhoefer thanks for providing the link, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `rxjs` version 5, you can implement doOnSubscribe using pure functions instead of patching the prototype. This way you won't need the type augmentation.

```typescript
import {defer} from 'rxjs/observable/defer';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

/** Example
import {from} from 'rxjs/observable/from';

from([1, 2, 3])
    .pipe(doOnSubscribe(() => console.log('subscribed to stream')))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x), null, () => console.log('completed'));
*/

export function doOnSubscribe<T>(onSubscribe: () => void): (source: Observable<T>) =>  Observable<T> {
    return function inner(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
        return defer(() => {
          onSubscribe();

          return source;
        });
    };
}
```

https://gist.github.com/evxn/750702f7c8e8d5a32c7b53167fe14d8d