# Rxjs actions on observable start (opponent of finalize)

Tags: angular, rxjs

On my current Angular project I need to do specific actions when subscribing to an observable.
Thus I'm looking for, let's say, the opponent of finalize operator.
Finalize operator call a function when observable completes or errors. In my case I need to call a function when the observable start.
=> Do you know how I can si this ?

Update to clarify my request:
In a service I have an init methode returning an Observable.
Thanks to pipable operator all the logic is iniside the observable because the 
initObservable may be **subscribed in several components** (avoid code duplication) **simultaneously** (that's why I use share operator) ex:

```
private initObs$: Observable<Data> = htttp.get('URL form where I get Data').pipe(
    tap(// do stuff with Data (init the store with Data in my case)),
    catchError(//Error handeling),
    finalize(// do onComplete actions ex: hide spiner overlay),
    share() // As this observable may be subscribed simultaneously by different subscriber
);
```

As this Obsevable may be subscribed in **different components and simultaneously**, I want to add the action of showing the spinner Overlay inside the Observable itself to avoid code like below in every components:

```
this.spinnerservice.show();
this.DataService.initObs$.subscribe();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881510/rxjs-adding-a-function-to-observable-to-execute-when-subscribed-to-defer/46881782#46881782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're looking for defer:

```
initObs$ = defer(() => {
  // do whatever, show spinner etc
  return htttp.get('URL form where I get Data').pipe(
    tap(// do stuff with Data (init the store with Data in my case)),
    catchError(//Error handeling),
    finalize(// do onComplete actions ex: hide spiner overlay)
  );
}).pipe(share());
```

Comment: you're right that was exactly what I was looking for I just made an exemple: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-aj1jv7

Comment: So does that answer your question? Or is there more?